# Why doesn't my ajax post want to work? I've tried serializing the form data, and I've tried sending the data as separate variables. Neither work

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

The echo in my PHP file doesn't work, and my ajax if-else doesn't do anything. A bit lost here. Any help would be appreciated:

It's a basic login page. The loginVerify() function validates that the fields aren't empty. The .post in my signupVerify() doesn't work either. The functions are working, as the alerts go off. So I don't really know what could be wrong with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Tasks</title>

    <!-- We can add an icon later for tasks -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/size.png"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="styles.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function loginVerify(){
            var uname = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var data = $('#form').serialize();
            alert('hello');
            $.ajax({
                url:"login.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        alert("The email is incorrect");
                    } else {
                        alert("HELLO");
                    }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }

        function signupVerify(){
            var uname = document.getElementById("email2").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password2").value;
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
            var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
            var college = document.getElementById("college").value;
            var major = document.getElementById("major").value;
            var regularExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;

            if (!password.match(regularExpression)){
                alert("Password must contain at least one special character and one number, and be at least 6 characters long.");
            }
            if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(fname))){
                alert("First name should contain no numbers or special characters.");
            }
            if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(lname))){
                alert("Last name should contain no numbers or special characters.");
            }
            else{
                alert("HELLO");
            }
            $.post("signup.php",{username:uname,password:password,fname:fname,lname:lname,college:college,major:major},function(data) {
                if (data == '0') {
                    alert("The email is incorrect");
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- <div class="col-sm-12  text-center">
    <h1>My Tasks</h1>
</div> -->

<div class="row container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md nav-justified
                bg-primary navbar-light" style="width:100%">



        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav" style="width:100%">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <h1>My Tasks!</h1> -->
                        <h1 class= "text-white">My Tasks!</h1>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center mt-2">
            <h1>Sign up or Login!</h1>
        </div>

        <!--LOGIN-->
        <div class="col-6 text-center container-fluid">
            <form onsubmit="loginVerify()" id="form">
                <!-- Username Div--> 
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                        placeholder="Username" name="username">
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <!-- Password Div-->
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"
                            placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-2">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- SIGN UP -->
        <div class="col-6 text-center">
            <form onsubmit="signupVerify()" id="form2">
                <!-- User name Div-->
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 justify-content-around">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email2"
                            placeholder="Username" name="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 justify-content-around">
                        <label for="username">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2"
                            placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 justify-content-around">
                        <label for="username">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname"
                            placeholder="First Name" name="fname">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 justify-content-around">
                        <label for="username">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname"
                            placeholder="Last Name" name="lname">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 justify-content-around">
                        <label for="username">College:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="college"
                            placeholder="College" name="college">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 justify-content-around">
                        <label for="username">Major:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="major"
                            placeholder="Major" name="major">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-2">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>


    <footer class="footer page-footer font-small">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="text-muted">&copy; IS218 Group 2, 2020 |  Terms Of Use  |  Privacy Statement</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center pt-5 mt-5">
    
   
</div>

<script src="check.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the PHP file login that's referenced in the first function.

```
    <?php
    echo "Hello";
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    return $username;

    require_once('session.php');

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a `success` return from your PHP? What about if you add an `error(data)` function as well? Do you need to prevent the default form action in your Ajax too?

Comment: First Debug Test = `print_r($_POST);` does that show anything

Comment: `data == '0'` will never be true. You have `Hello` and `username` before that. The `return` should also be `echo`. Also doesn't look you do anything with a return that isn't `0`.

Comment: you are using slim minified version of JQuery which takes out ajax function, please look for that as well

Comment: I changed my if to just if(data) and I only return $username. I added an error but nothing shows up.

Comment: But I also link the ajax library.

Comment: Remove or comment out the Jquery slim script line at the end of the document. JQuery slim does NOT contain the $.ajax function (you should be getting a console error stating $.ajax is not a function )...  And why are you including JQuery 3 times (2 in the header and 1 in the footer) ?!

Comment: Damn, I didn't even notice that. This is a group project and I was just supposed to do the database and javascript bits. Works properly now! Thanks!